# Javascript Regex: Replacing multiple words with a space for all occurrences?

Tags: javascript

How can I replace all occurrences of double quotes and single quotes with a space with javascript regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stripped = mystring.replace(/["']/g, " ");
```